# How to send Ansible debug messages to another file?

Tags: logging, ansible, debug

If you do the following:

```
- name: print to stdout
  command: echo "My log information"
  register: logdata

- debug: msg="{{ logdata.stdout }}"
```

The `logdata` register variable's contents will be displayed along with the complete ansible log. I would like these debug messages to be stored in another file. Is this possible by any means?

The other alternative I thought of was to have an array of register variables. And finally use the `copy` module to put the content of that array to a file. Not the best option. If it is possible to redirect the stdout of `debug` to another file, it would be cool.

Answer (score 4):

Use local_action as under after capturing the output in a variable:

```
- local_action: 
        module: copy 
        content: "{{ variable1 }}"
        dest: /tmp/whatever.out
```

Comment: nicely done. clean and simple. works great on `ansible 2.8.6`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lineinfile module?

```
- lineinfile: create=yes regexp="NONEXISTENTLINE" dest=/tmp/ansible.log line="{{logdata.stdout}}" state=present
```

I use regexp="NONEXISTENTLINE" to allow the same message to be logged several times. Maybe you don't need that.

The log will be on each target host. Pull it or not.

Alternatively, you can parse the output with awk or something.

Comment: That's really a clever hack

Answer (score 0):

> ***How to send Ansible `debug` messages to another file?***

Without writing any task(s), re-implementing functionality which is already there, just by configuration and whitelisting an additional [Callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html), see [Index of all Callback Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html), namely [`log_plays` callback – write playbook output to log file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/log_plays_callback.html).

With an `ansible.cfg`

```ini
[default]
stdout_callback         = yaml
callback_whitelist      = timer, profile_tasks, log_plays

[callback_log_plays]
log_folder              = /tmp/ansible/hosts
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
```

will result into an `stdout` of

```yaml
PLAY [test] *********************************************************************************************
Saturday 14 October 2023  12:45:15 +0200 (0:00:00.041)       0:00:00.041 ******

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: Hello world!

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************
test.example.com  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
Saturday 14 October 2023  12:45:15 +0200 (0:00:00.068)       0:00:00.109 ******
===============================================================================
```

and a log file

```shell
~/test$ ll /tmp/ansible/hosts/
total 52
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users   314 Oct 14 12:45 test.example.com
```

with content

```shell
~/test$ cat /tmp/ansible/hosts/test.example.com
Oct 14 2023 12:45:15 - log_plays.yml -  - debug - OK - {"msg": "Hello world!", "changed": false, "_ansible_verbose_always": true, "_ansible_no_log": false}
```

**Similar and further Q&A**

- [How to use the callback plugin `log_plays` and keep `stdout` screen output simultaneously using `ansible-playbook`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77292546/6771046)

and regarding the [`log_plays` callback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/log_plays_callback.html) usage

- [Where is the host name derived from, for the name of the log file when using `log_plays` callback plugin in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77286744/6771046)